# I don't get the concept of using "this" and "that" in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, null, this, illegalstateexception

My problem is like in the following code, for example:

```
    public void removeSelfFromGrid()
    {
      if ( grid == null )
        throw new IllegalStateException(
              "This actor is not contained in a grid." );
      if ( grid.get( location ) != this )
        throw new IllegalStateException(
              "The grid contains a different actor at location "
                     + location + "." );

      grid.remove( location );
      grid = null;
      location = null;
    }
```

I learned it a long time ago, but I don't get the concept of `this` or `that`.

Answer (score 3):

Java only has `this` keyword, not `that`

`this` means, the current object on which you are invoking `removeSelfFromGrid` method.

> **Using the this Keyword**
>
> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

For more details, check it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

In your method, you have used `if ( grid.get( location ) != this )`, which means, the `location` object from `grid` and the current object (on which, you invoke `removeSelfFromGrid` method) are same or not

Comment: So it's boolean? Like a true-false value?

Comment: @user3363511 : Which is a boolean?